# how to remove the "new" link in doctrine admin generator

Tags: symfony1, doctrine, admin-generator

Im using the doctrine admin generator, and I want to not allow the user to create new records (just to show them), is there any way to do that by setting up the "generator.yml" ? I've succeeded to remove de batch and per items actions and everything else is working perfect, but can't remove the "new" link =(
This is what I have (the relevant part btw):

```
generator:
  params:
    config:
      list:
        batch_actions: {}
        object_actions:
          _delete: ~
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to change the "actions" value of list:

```
generator:
  params:
    config:
      list:
        actions: { }
```

You could restrict to a credential via:

```
generator:
  params:
    config:
      list:
        actions: { credentials: admin }
```

To clarify the difference between the action types:

- **batch_actions** - actions that can be performed on multiple items via the checkboxes and select widget at the bottom (e.g. bulk delete)
- **object_actions** - actions that are performed on a specific item (e.g. edit)
- **actions** - actions that appear in the list controls (e.g. new)